# How can I apply custom styles to my custom Button when first loaded?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I'm confused because custom styles are not applied when I try to create my Custom Control, inheriting from the Button class.

```
Public Class FlatButton : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Private ForeColorHover As Color = ForeColor
    Private CoreForeColor As Color
    Public Sub New()
        Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
        AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        FlatStyle = Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
        UseCompatibleTextRendering = True
        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
        ForeColor = CTL("text_color")
        Padding = New Padding(0)
        Margin = New Padding(0)
        AutoSize = True
    End Sub
    Public Property _OnHoveringColor As Color
        Set(value As Color)
            ForeColorHover = value
        End Set
        Get
            Return ForeColorHover
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Property _OnHoveringBackColor As Color
        Set(value As Color)
            FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = value
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = value
        End Set
        Get
            Return FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

When I add this Control to a `Form.Controls` collection in code, it works fine. It doesn't when dropped from the Toolbox.

```
Public Sub New()
    Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
    AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    FlatStyle = Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
    UseCompatibleTextRendering = True
    FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
    ForeColor = CTL("text_color")
    Padding = New Padding(0)
    Margin = New Padding(0)
    AutoSize = True
End Sub
```

Works only when manually added with code:
(below is the code in Form.Load)

```
For Each item As Object In items
    'always create new button while looping
    Dim newSubButton As New FlatButton
    With newSubButton
        .Name = "btn" & item.ToString()
        .Text = item.ToString()
        .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left And AnchorStyles.Top
        .Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 14, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
        .Location = New Size(LastAddedButtonAsXLoc + IIf(Array.IndexOf(items, item) = 0, 0 * Gap + 75, 1 * Gap), (pnlSubHeader.Height / 2) - newSubButton.Height)
    End With
    AddHandler newSubButton.Click, AddressOf SetTaskButton
    If TaskState.Count < 1 Then newSubButton.PerformClick()
    pnlSubHeader.Controls.Add(newSubButton)
    LastAddedButtonAsXLoc = newSubButton.Location.X + newSubButton.Width
Next
```

Comment: Not clear what is not working for you here. The Properties you set in the Constructor of course will be set when you create the Control dropping one from the ToolBox. Also when you create a new instance in code. What happens that is different from what you were expecting? -- What is this: `ForeColor = CTL("text_color")`?.

Comment: @Jimi i know what you mean, it would be set...but its not.I dont know whats wrong, maybe from my code or else...well im still looking for the solution, thanks for commenting and the code ya asking for its just shorthand code of getting data from my project settings(a.k.a hex color)...its came from ```
Public Function GetData(ByVal item As String)
        Return My.Settings(item)
    End Function ;
    Public Function CTL(ByVal color As String) As Color
        Return ColorTranslator.FromHtml(GetData(color))
    End Function 
``` which coded inside custom module

Comment: Try to remove that function call and just set `ForeColor = Color.Red`. Remove any Control of this class from any Form, rebuild the Project, drop a new one. See that you have a single instance of this Control in a single Form while you're working with it. If you change something relevant (add other Constuctors, new Properties, modify the name of properties or method, add function calls in methods overrides), remove the Control instance, save, rebuild, drop a new one. Mandatory with UserControls.

Comment: awesome...ofc i forgot to rebuild the project.its working now,thanks @Jimi ✨

Comment: Don't add SOLVED to the question's title. Since you solved the problem, either post an answer that explain what you did or delete the question (since it actually looks like a *problem* not directly reproducible).

Comment: Sorry, i'm new here. Thanks for notice